# opencart domain .htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, opencart

I have a domain with open cart installed and I also have SSL on my site. If anyone hits our site through
http://www.example .com/pageseo

they're automatically redirected to

https://www.example .com/index.php? *route*=pageseo

How can we possibly get rid of this index.php? *route*= Please advise?

Here is my .htaccess code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need go to catalog `system/library`, in file `response.php` find line with `public function output()` and after it insert:

```
if (!defined('HTTP_CATALOG')) $this->output = str_replace('index.php?route=common/home', '', $this->output);
```

Additionaly add in your .htaccess file next:

```
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: optio still have the same issues

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, haven't tested it with Opencart but it works elsewhere.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```